# VMware Fusion won't boot my Boot Camp partition

Tags: boot-camp, vmware-fusion

I have a Boot Camp partition on my MacBook that I would ultimately like to convert to a VMware virtual machine image. I've installed VMware Fusion and tried to start up my Boot Camp install using the Boot Camp button on the initial welcome screen. It brings up the "VMware Fusion is preparing your Boot Camp partition to run as a virtual machine" dialog, but afterward it shows an error dialog with the following message:

```
Boot Camp partition preprocessing failed.
You may not be able to boot your Boot Camp partition as a virtual machine.
```

It then tries to boot the new VM, but it blue screens during the boot process. The info on the blue screen doesn't provide much in the way of help though. Running chkdsk has no effect.

[image: Blue Screen]

After searching around, some people recommended using VMware's stand-alone converter utility from within Windows to create an image, but the utility said it couldn't create an image because my disk uses a GUID Partition Table (GPT). I'm wondering if this is why it can't boot my BC partition from Fusion. Has anyone else run into this and found a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having seen something similar in the vmware forum discussions and went there to find a post (you can search more if this is not the one) that might help you.

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/186884

have not played with this for quite some time, but i know it can be done, though not as consistent as you use a virtual disk.

windows, unlike say linux, is very sensitive to hw so blue screen is common in booting a vm from a partition whatever the host.